# How to add linebreaks in iPhone programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to know how to add a linebreak in plain text such as UILabel.

Soli...there is an amendment at here....

The linebreaks will added on the plain text on SMS or any notification alert message.

So, the "escape sequence" can used as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, and I'm not sure if it'll display properly, but have you tried putting \n in your NSString?

```
myLabel.text = @"First Line\nSecond Line";
```

Answer (score 3):

set the property `numberOfLines` of the label to `0`. Then,

`yourlabel.text = @"Line 1\nLine2";`

will display as:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The escape sequence "\n" adds a newline.

`@"Line one\nLine two"` will display as

```
Line one
Line two
```